# wordpress image upload folder messed up

Tags: php, wordpress, image, web

So I messed up with images on wordpress. I un-ticked the box that makes the images sorted by year and month, By my lack of reading I moved everything out of the dated folders and just into /wp-content/uploads. I then added in this code snippet `define( ‘UPLOADS’, ‘wp-content/uploads’ );` to make them go to the new location, However it now tries to go to “/wp-content/uploads/datedfolder/datedfolder/image” is there anything I can do to fix my error

Comment: How many things did you add after defining `UPLOADS`? I'd just remove that, you should be part the way there. Any change you have a backup? That might just be easier.

Comment: I added no more images after defining upload. even with it gone it still goes for wp-content/uploads/date/date/image, note the two year and month date folders are removed

Comment: i would prefer to do it in this folder config instead of a backup as it will help me setup a cloudflare worker to change them to cloudflare images images